# Is it possible to summon Moon Lord again?

Tags: terraria

I had already defeated the Moon Lord and The Cultists weren't at the dungeon so I couldn't kill them again to start the event and summon the pillars. Does this mean I have to start a new world?

Answer (score 6):

You need to wait about one in game day, or simply exit and re-open the world.

Answer (score 1):

Alternatively, use a [Celestial Sigil](https://terraria.fandom.com/wiki/Celestial_Sigil) that is crafted with 20 of each Lunar Fragment (Solar, Nebula, Stardust, Vortex) at an Ancient Manipulator.